# Error in Perl code: Can't locate loadable object for module XML::LibXSLT

Tags: perl, apache, centos5

```
Environment: CentOS 5.
Application: Perl 5.8.8
```

Apache error saying

```
Error in Perl code: Can't locate loadable object for module XML::LibXSLT
```

It requires following modules:

```
XML::LibXSLT
```

and

```
XML::LibXML
```

Both require v 1.70, I have installed both.

My question is, It is saying "cant locate loadable object for module"

What module it is exactly looking for ? Further as far as required perl modules... They are all installed and up there.

Is there any debugging method like what exactly it is looking for ?

Comment: These modules load C code, and Perl can't find the `.so` file for that module. How did you install the modules? With the `cpan` or `cpanm` command line tools, with a package manager like `yum` or `ppm`, or manually by `perl Makefile.PL && make && make test && make install`? Did the install and tests complete without errors? Did you install the 3rd party libxml and libxslt libraries? Your install is botched, and only completed halfway.

Comment: I have installed it through `perl Makefile.PL && make && make test && make install` these worked without errors. All I have a small doubt now like I have installed **libxml2** from source and then when did not work, I again installed it through rpm packages via YUM. But that should not impact I guess anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

A "loadable object" is a C library that the Perl module needs in order to do its work. To fix it, you probably need to run the following commands.

```
$ sudo yum install libxml2
$ sudo yum install libxslt
```

I'm surprised that these libraries are missing. How did you install the modules? If you used `yum` then they would have been installed as dependencies and if you used `cpan` (or `cpanm`) then Perl wouldn't have been able to build the modules without these libraries installed.

**Update:** I've just seen in another reply that you are installing this modules manually. Is there any reason why you're not using `yum` to install them?

```
$ sudo yum install perl-XML-LibXML
$ sudo yum install perl-XML-LibXSLT
```

Comment: I have already installed these core C modules, but something  else is wrong here. I am using Libxml2-2.6.32 and libxslt-1.1.18 for this module. and both perl modules are version 1.70.